# Как добавить программу в автозагрузку?

Tags: linux, c, автозагрузка

ОС Ubuntu. Задача такая: необходимо написать программу на Си, которая при запуске добавляет себя в автозагрузку. Под автозагрузкой предполагается следующее: после того, как эта программа исполняется, в дальнейшем при каждом страте системы, она должна автоматически запускаться. Есть одно ограничение: нельзя вручную добавлять программу в автозагрузку, программа должна делать это сама.
Какие есть способы реализации данной задачи?

Comment: [Автозагрузка в Ubuntu](https://losst.pro/avtozagruzka-v-ubuntu) ваша прога должна записать в директорию файл `~/.config/autostart/имя.desktop` с содержимым, описанным по ссылке.

Comment: @AlexGlebe ~/.config/autostart выполняется НЕ при старте системы. Из упомянутых по ссылке способов выполняется при старте системы только rc.local, однако как минимум с 18.04 это было удалено

Comment: @andreymal ну тогда прозевал. Тогда не понимаю, при чём тут старт системы и простой юзер?

Comment: а что программа должна делать кроме этого? автозагрузок в линуксах 100500 видов